# Installing Asp.net 3.5 sp1 on windows 2008 web server edition

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql

I am trying to install sql server 2012 on windows 2008 web server edition but failing as asp.net 3.5 sp1 is missing.

I cannot add asp.net 3.5 on this version as there is no 'Application Server' role.

Whenever I try to install from asp.net 3.5 setup, it will say you need to run through role,

I am stuck now..

Can any one please help?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install the Application Server role to enable it, you enable it through the Features section.

`Server Manager --> Features --> .Net Framework 3.5.1`